# How do I weight and combine scores in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, date-arithmetic

I am trying to create a single rating, an example would be I have a rating for Sample 1 of 85 and a rating for Sample 2 of 65 all from Group A.
 I want to assign a weight of 70% to Sample 1 and 30% to Sample 2, then combine those together for one overall rating using this Group A rating to compare with Group B.
(Ex. 85*70%(59.5) + 65*30%(19.5) = Group A =79, Group B 84)

Comment: Give a glimpse on how your database is structured. Then, what you expect to be the end result (meaning, what you want on screen). Additionally, what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column called Rating and another called Weight, then based on your example, just create a calculated field called, say Weighted_Rating = Weight * Rating.

Then the SUM(Weighted_Rating) should give the results you describe -- assuming you have a dimension on the sheet that partitions the data into groups A and B.

Comment: Here is a sample, in Excel, for what i'm trying to do. SRVY_RSPNDNT_ID SRVY_RSPNS_DT Rating Group Sample Weighted
8FpFEoNIFI5sAhtZsp84cA4C 3/7/2015 78 3 A 
AkAhNptwsR85JFAc9kxxIg4C 6/14/2014 100 2 A 70
c9V9ZlBxwUcZZ5FVMpRwZA4C 5/4/2014 85 3 A 
cEJVc1N1k4MQ4J4d5xkBsA4C 12/12/2014 96 2 A 67.2
cs58N9NNpMsthgdVhp4ExQ4C 11/30/2014 78 2 B 23.4
csg1EcgYoRdBp9sdF50pBg4C 3/17/2015 74 1 A 
cZck80VcAcYcU48cc89J9A4C 5/13/2014 78 3 A 
FE98dJEppgw5ABUNVsQEpQ4C 12/19/2014 100 1 A 
hN1gZQ1ZoJV5IwcIspBlUg4C 5/29/2014 100 2 B 30

Comment: Please, put this information on your question, on a decent format